# Could not build Objective-C module 'RealmSwift'

Tags: swift, realm

When I try to import RealmSwift I got this `Could not build Objective-C module 'RealmSwift'`

```
 using enum realm::sync::ProtocolError;
        switch (static_cast<realm::sync::ProtocolError>
 Expected unqualified-id
```

How to solve this problem? thank you!

I tried to use RealmSwift.framework for my app.I installed  Realm using CocoaPods and tried to import RealmSwift packages.

Comment: When asking questions, it's Best Practice to include details about the issue. Please update your question by including the version of XCode you're using, along with your Cocoapods and Realm version and include your podfile. Also indicate if this is macOS or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to downgrade the realm version until it's compatible with your Xcode version
you can verify it in the [releases notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases) for the realm
until the version

> `pod 'RealmSwift', '10.33.0'`

it was compatible with `Xcode: 13.1-14.1` and after they update to `Xcode: 13.3-14.2.`

Answer (score -1):

"Could not build Objective-C module 'RealmSwift'"

To fix this error message in Xcode, simply follow steps 1 to 3 below. That's the end of the problem.

1. Go to Product - Scheme - New Scheme
2. Choose ‘RealmSwift’ from the Drop-Down Menu
3. Then click ‘OK’
4. The problem should be solved

You are happy now!